# Mule 4 - Look for a value in json and derive corresponding jsons value

Tags: arrays, json, dataweave, mule4

Here I need look for a value1 (color/size) in my json arrayObject and map to value2 (yellow/28 inch) of same json array object in mule 4 dataweave. Below is my json input

Kindly note `systemAttributeName` should not be same as `group`.
Only if `group == 'Color'`, then corresponding `systemAttributeName` should be populated

**JSON Input**

```
{
  "system": "Computer",
  "description": "",
  "details": "",
  "systemDetails": [
    {
      "systemnumber": "A123",
      "description": [
        {
          "group": "color",
          "desc": "yellow"
        },
         {
          "group": "variant",
          "desc": "20k model"
        },
        {
          "group": "category",
          "desc": "Desktop"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "systemnumber": "B123",
      "description": [
        {
          "group": "size",
          "desc": "28 inch"
        },
        {
          "group": "category",
          "desc": "Laptop"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**My expected output is as below**

```
{
  "systemId": "A123",
  "systemLevelDetails": [
    {
      "systemAttributeName": "Colordescription", 
      "values": "yellow"
    },// if my corresponding input systemDetails.description has a group 'color' - then this should be present
    {
      "systemAttributeName": "Categorydescription",
      "values": "Desktop"
    }// if my corresponding input systemDetails.description has a group 'category' - then this should be present
  ]
}

{
  "systemId": "B123",
  "systemLevelDetails": [
    {
      "systemAttributeName": "Sizedescription",
      "values": "28inch"
    },// if my corresponding input systemDetails.description has a group 'size' - then this should be present
    {
      "systemAttributeName": "Categorydescription",
      "values": "Laptop"
    }
  ]
}
```

Let me know how can I achieve this?

Comment: The output is invalid JSON. Do you mean the output should be an array?

Comment: "Kindly note systemAttributeName should not be same as group." this is not correct. It seems that the value should be same, just some values are filtered out in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the output should be an array (because what else could it be?), it just seems to be the same as  `payload.systemDetails` but with the key names changed. One way to do it is to just use map and a nested map for the nested array in `description`. If only some values in `description.group` are allowed we can use the filter() function to remove them, by validating if the `group` value is present in a list of valid values.
DataWeave script:

```js
%dw 2.0
import capitalize from dw::core::Strings
output application/json
var validGroups=["color", "size", "category"]
---
payload.systemDetails map {
    systemId: $.systemnumber,
    systemLevelDetails: $.description 
        filter (validGroups contains $.group)
        map {
            systemAttributeName: capitalize($.group)++"description",
            values: $.desc
        }
}
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "systemId": "A123",
    "systemLevelDetails": [
      {
        "systemAttributeName": "Colordescription",
        "values": "yellow"
      },
      {
        "systemAttributeName": "Categorydescription",
        "values": "Desktop"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "systemId": "B123",
    "systemLevelDetails": [
      {
        "systemAttributeName": "Sizedescription",
        "values": "28 inch"
      },
      {
        "systemAttributeName": "Categorydescription",
        "values": "Laptop"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

If you need to process each item of the output array individually just use a `<foreach>` scope in the flow.

Comment: thank you, I do not need systemAttributeName as what is present in group. I need to check if group=='Color' then in output get corresponding values of 'Color's Desc'

Comment: What about 'category' and 'size'?

Comment: I updated my answer to match the updated example in the question.

Comment: Only 3 values are allowed in my output, if group has color - corresponding color, same with category and size .., but if any other details like variant is present in group - those should be ignored.. So here i need to first validate if $.group=='Color' and take corresponding desc and map.

Comment: I have already updated my answer.

Comment: systemAttributeName field is not same as group field., for group==color, systemAttributeName is 'colordescription' // which has to be hardcoded. for group==size, systemAttributeName is 'sizedescription' // which has to be hardcoded. But if i hardcode as 'colorDescription' to systemAttributeName, then i will not be able to get SizeDescription/CategoryDescription

Comment: I missed it, my bad. I fixed my answer. There is no need to hardcode anything since my script already has validated that `group` values are restricted I just transform it.